# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS / 5.10.0-*-oem kernel breaks USB sound and video

Tags: usb, webcam, lsusb

Since the upgrade to the 5.10.-oem kernel my USB Webcam/Microphone no longer works. Also, the command "lsusb" simply seems to hang and never returns.
Everything was still working with the 5.6-generic kernels.
Is this a known problem? I could not find any reported issues in this regard.

I would like to switch back to the latest 5.6-generic kernel, what is the safest way to do re-install older kernels without breaking my setup?

Current Kernel is 5.10.0-1019-oem #20-Ubuntu SMP.
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do not know where you are getting these kernels from Ubuntu 20.04 ships with 5.4 and upgrades to 5.8 only those 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: @David, there are some OEM kernels that differ; eg. https://code.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/focal (5.6, 5.10) , however Fant the generic kernels will be 5.4 or 5.8 (not 5.6 I believe which is an OEM kernel only in Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes but since you are having a problem I would only use the standard supported ones.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. As a side effect I cannot gracefully reboot my PC. I have to hard reset it with the physical button. If I boot from `5.10.0-1016-oem` everything works fine. The kernels after all exhibit the same issue.

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes, the reboot issue is there, too.

Comment: My question was not how to boot into an older kernel, but how to safely re-install older kernels without breaking my setup.

Comment: @David There are perfectly legit reasons to need to use the oem kernel, don't try to force solutions on people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See launchpad bug reports 1918670 1920032

Reboot computer and press ESC key prior to Ubuntu spinner to open the grub menu

Select Advanced options from grub menu to show list of available kernels

Select known working kernel (in my case it was 5.10.0-1016-oem)

After computer finishes booting up open synaptic package manager

sudo apt install synaptic (if not already installed)

Under Sections heading select Kernels and modules and sort for your installed kernels

Select the 5.10.0-1019-oem kernel images to be deleted

select your preferred kernel 5.6? for reinstallation

Select Apply changes

After closing out of synaptic, for good measure I updated grub just to make sure things looked right before rebooting the computer

sudo update-grub

reboot